# connecting socketcluster servers

Tags: node.js, websocket, socketcluster

I'm trying to implement this [solution](https://github.com/SocketCluster/socketcluster/blob/master/scc-guide.md) (on Win10 x64), but for some reason all the SocketCluster nodes refuse to communicate with each other.

[image]

Sothis is my cur. configuration:

- 1 StateServer [7777]
- 1 BrokerServer [8888]
- 2 SocketCluster servers running on ports [ 8000, 8001]
- 1 LoadBalancer [2000] to divide the trafic between the 2 nodes.

I ensured that both the State and Broker severs are listening:

```
  TCP    [::]:7777              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8888              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

From what I've understood so far, `BrokerServer` along with the `SocketCluster` nodes should all connect to the `StatusServer`(?)

I could successfully connect the `BrokerServer` to `StateServer`, but whenever I try to connect any of the `SocketCluster` services, it reports 'socket hung' errors.

`StateServer`:

```
SC Cluster State Server is listening on port 7777
Sever d08298c6-523f-4c1b-9fcc-efd4e92fab22 at address undefined on port 8888 joined the cluster
Client 10612bde-514f-40d3-9340-7179a1901376 at address undefined joined the cluster
Cluster state converged to active:["ws://[undefined]:8888"]
```

`SocketCluster` instance:

```
{ SocketProtocolError: Socket hung up
    at Emitter.SCSocket._onSCClose (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\scsocket.js:596:15)
    at Emitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\scsocket.js:285:12)
    at Emitter.emit (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:131:20)
    at Emitter.SCEmitter.emit (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\sc-emitter\index.js:28:26)
    at Emitter.SCTransport._onClose (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.js:175:30)
    at WebSocket.wsSocket.onerror (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\socketcluster-client\lib\sctransport.js:104:12)
    at WebSocket.onError (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sc-cluster-broker-client\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:452:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\socketcluster\node_modules\sc-domain\index.js:12:31)
  name: 'SocketProtocolError',
  message: 'Socket hung up',
  code: 1006 }
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue on linux with latest versions of state version, broker and socketcluster repos. Did you find any workaround.?

Comment: well , as soon as I switched to Ubuntu, everything started to work . Haven't tested the latest repo though.

Comment: I am currently on ubuntu only. Its not working. Dunno what is wrong.

Comment: The main thing is the socketcluster repo don't have a server.js file in its root directory now. So, I did an 'npm install socketcluster -g' and then 'npm create myApp' which creates an app. I am running socketcluster referring to state server from inside myApp. Do you think I should be doing something else.!

Answer (score 2):

Are you running those instances in Docker containers by any chance?

Based on the log output that you're getting from the state server (address undefined), it looks like the scc-state instance cannot figure out your instances' IP addresses. This can happen for several reasons. For example, running an instance inside a Docker container can obscure that instance's real IP address. It's also possible that running SCC on Windows could cause similar problems.

The solution to this problem is to set an `SCC_INSTANCE_IP` environment variable when launching each instance - This environment variable should hold the IP address of the instance which other instances can use to connect to it (if using Docker, you can use the `docker inspect` command to find the  private network IP address of a specific container).

`SCC_INSTANCE_IP` can be either a private IP address, public IP address or a hostname.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that scaling the cluster horizontally isn't working properly on Windows OS yet (using the current version v.1.2.1).
Both `SocketCluster` nodes aren't communicating with the `brokerServer` for some reason.